# Local project/package failing to import

Tags: typescript, react-native, yarn-v2, yarn-lock.json

My project is failing to import a local package that I linked even though I have verified that it was successfully installed through `yarn list --pattern @packagename`.

Whenever I try to run yarn start, I get the error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/controllers/geoCode/getGeoCode.ts:5:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@packrat/packages' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

And whenever I hover my mouse over the import path, it tells me :

```
Cannot find module '@packrat/packages' or its corresponding type declarations
```

This is how I import it:

```
import * as validators from '@packrat/packages';
```

Running `yarn list --pattern @packrat/packages` returns the package and the version successfully.

Package.json file of @packrat/packages

```
{
  "name": "@packrat/packages",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "source": "src/index.ts",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 tsc",
    "build:and:install": "yarn build && yarn"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "zod": "^3.22.2"
  }
}
```

package.json file of lib I'm trying to use it in:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 tsc",
    "debug": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect-brk' nodemon",
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "lint": "eslint . --fix --ext .ts",
    "setup": "echo \"No setup needed\"",
    "start:pm2": "pm2 start dist/index.js --name server",
    "start:prod": "node dist/index.js",
    "start:ts-node": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "start": "nodemon",
    "test:expect": "mocha 'generated/test/**/*.spec.js'",
    "test:generate": "npx openapi-generator url http://localhost:3000/swagger.json -d ./generated -t javascript",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet\""
  },
  "author": "Andrew Bierman",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hono/node-server": "^1.2.0",
    "@hono/trpc-server": "^0.1.0",
    "@packrat/packages": "*",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "@trpc/client": "^10.38.5",
    "@trpc/server": "^10.38.5",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/csurf": "^1.11.2",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.3",
    "@types/swagger-jsdoc": "^6.0.1",
    "@types/swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.3",
    "@types/validator": "^13.11.1",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "bull": "^4.10.4",
    "celebrate": "^15.0.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-rate-limit": "^6.9.0",
    "firebase": "^9.19.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "google-auth-library": "^8.8.0",
    "googleapis": "^118.0.0",
    "helmet": "^7.0.0",
    "hono": "^3.8.0",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "joi": "^17.9.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^7.4.0",
    "mongoose-autopopulate": "^1.0.1",
    "mongoose-to-swagger": "^1.4.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.1",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "openai": "^3.3.0",
    "osmtogeojson": "^3.0.0-beta.5",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "piscina": "^4.0.0",
    "superjson": "^2.0.0",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.8",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.6.3",
    "trpc-panel": "^1.3.4",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.9.0",
    "zod": "^3.22.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli": "^2.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.4.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^38.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^16.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "expect.js": "^0.3.1",
    "jest": "^29.6.2",
    "migrate-mongo": "^10.0.0",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "openapi-generator": "^0.1.39",
    "prettier": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/generated/test/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/generated/test/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have checked my node modules and I see the package there but still unable to import.

I deleted my node_modules folder and reinstalled it again(`yarn install`), yet didn't work.

When I deleted my yarn.lock file and tried to add it back using `yarn import`, I get this warning for some packages including the one causing the above error:

```
warning Import of "workspace-aggregator-a8c2b955-e28b-48c4-ae6b-f5f23dad4686@1.0.0" for "packrat-world" failed, resolving normally.
warning Import of "packrat@1.0.0" for "packrat-world" failed, resolving normally.
warning Import of "@packrat/packages@0.0.1" for "packrat-world" failed, resolving normally.
warning Import of "check-dependency-version-consistency@^4.1.0" for "packrat-world" failed, resolving normally.
warning Import of "@manypkg/cli@^0.21.0" for "packrat-world" failed, resolving normally.
warning Import of "server@1.0.0" for "packrat-world" failed, resolving normally.
warning Import of "cross-env@^7.0.3" for "packrat-world" failed, resolving normally.
warning Import of "husky@^8.0.0" for "packrat-world" failed, resolving normally.
warning Import of "dotenv-cli@^7.3.0" for "packrat-world" failed, resolving normally.
warning Import of "lint-staged@^14.0.1" for "packrat-world" failed, resolving normally.
warning Import of "typescript@^5.2.2" for "packrat-world" failed, resolving normally.
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@packrat%2fpackages: Not found".
```

It seems the error is due to my yarn.lock not able to import it, but I don't know how exactly to solve it

EDIT: Just to note, I'm a newbie in yarn. This project wasn't set up by me, so any suggestions no matter how stupid would help.